# PostgreSQL Large List-based Partition Unused

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-10

I have a large partitioned table. Partition keys are defined as a long list of discontinuous IDs. E.g.:

```
Partition of: foo_partitioned FOR VALUES IN (1733, 1731, 1800, 1732, 1799, 1798, 1804, 1803, 1802, 1801, 1797, 1796, 1795, 1794, 1793, 1792, 1791, 1790, 1789, 1788, 1787, 1786, 
1785, 1784, 1783, 1715, 1714, 1713, 1712, 1711, 1710, 1709, 1708, 1707, 1706, 1705, 1704, 1703, 1702, 1701, 1700, 1699, 1698, 1697, 1696, 1695, 1694, 1693, 1692, 1691, 1689, 
1688, 1687, 1686, 1685, 1684, 1683, 1682, 1681, 1680, 1679, 1658, 1657, 1656, 1655, 1654, 1653, 1652, 1651, 1650, 1649, 1648, 1647, 1646, 1645, 1644, 1643, 1642, 1641, 1640, 
1639, 1638, 1637, 1636, 1635, 1634, 1633, 1632, 1631, 1630, 1629, 1628, 1627, 1626, 1625, 1624, 1623, 1622, 1581, 1580, 1579, 1578, 1577, 1569, 1568, 1567, 1547, 1546, 1545, 
1549, 1550, 1551, 1552, 1553, 1554, 1555, 1556, 1557, 1808, 1809, 1810, 1811, 1888, 1819, 1820, 1821, 1822, 1823, 1824, 1825, 1826, 1827, 1828, 1829, 1830, 1831, 1832, 1833, 
1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841, 1842, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 
1863, 1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 1871, 1872, 1873, 1874, 1875, 1876, 1877, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 1882, 1883, 1884, 1885, 1886, 1887, 1889, 1890, 1891, 1892, 
1893, 1894, 1895, 1896, 1897, 1898, 1899, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908, 1909, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918, 1919, 1920, 1921, 
1922, 1923, 1924, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 
1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1959, 1960, 1961)

Partition constraint: ((bar_id IS NOT NULL) AND (bar_id = ANY (ARRAY[1733, 1731, 1800, 1732, 1799, 1798, 1804, 1803, 1802, 1801, 1797, 1796, 1795, 1794, 1793, 1792, 1791, 1790, 
1789, 1788, 1787, 1786, 1785, 1784, 1783, 1715, 1714, 1713, 1712, 1711, 1710, 1709, 1708, 1707, 1706, 1705, 1704, 1703, 1702, 1701, 1700, 1699, 1698, 1697, 1696, 1695, 1694, 
1693, 1692, 1691, 1689, 1688, 1687, 1686, 1685, 1684, 1683, 1682, 1681, 1680, 1679, 1658, 1657, 1656, 1655, 1654, 1653, 1652, 1651, 1650, 1649, 1648, 1647, 1646, 1645, 1644, 
1643, 1642, 1641, 1640, 1639, 1638, 1637, 1636, 1635, 1634, 1633, 1632, 1631, 1630, 1629, 1628, 1627, 1626, 1625, 1624, 1623, 1622, 1581, 1580, 1579, 1578, 1577, 1569, 1568, 
1567, 1547, 1546, 1545, 1549, 1550, 1551, 1552, 1553, 1554, 1555, 1556, 1557, 1808, 1809, 1810, 1811, 1888, 1819, 1820, 1821, 1822, 1823, 1824, 1825, 1826, 1827, 1828, 1829, 
1830, 1831, 1832, 1833, 1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841, 1842, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 
1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 1871, 1872, 1873, 1874, 1875, 1876, 1877, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 1882, 1883, 1884, 1885, 1886, 1887, 
1889, 1890, 1891, 1892, 1893, 1894, 1895, 1896, 1897, 1898, 1899, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908, 1909, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 
1918, 1919, 1920, 1921, 1922, 1923, 1924, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 
1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1959, 1960, 1961])))
```

When running explain against a query that matches this exact list of values using an IN clause, the planner tries to scan all partitions. Even when doing something simple such as looking at one value:

```
select * from foo_partitioned where bar_id=1733;
```

The query planner checks every partition.

```
Append  (cost=102.95..365378.32 rows=378224 width=36)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_partitioned_8  (cost=102.95..3508.07 rows=4571 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uq_foo_partitioned_8  (cost=0.00..101.81 rows=4571 width=0)
               Index Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
   ->  Index Scan using uq_foo_partitioned_16 on foo_partitioned_16  (cost=0.56..55328.46 rows=62937 width=36)
         Index Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_partitioned_25  (cost=1.30..6.52 rows=6 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uq_foo_partitioned_25  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=6 width=0)
               Index Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_partitioned_26  (cost=1.30..6.52 rows=6 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uq_foo_partitioned_26  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=6 width=0)
               Index Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_partitioned_27  (cost=1.30..6.52 rows=6 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uq_foo_partitioned_27  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=6 width=0)
               Index Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_partitioned_28  (cost=1.30..6.52 rows=6 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uq_foo_partitioned_28  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=6 width=0)
               Index Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_partitioned_29  (cost=347.37..14554.48 rows=15528 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: (bar_id = 1732)
...
```

Is there a better way to either 
a) define the tables such that constraint exclusion is actually used (I have it set to partition) or
b) write the query so constraint exclusion is actually used?

I've tried looking at the [code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/partitioning/partprune.c) for a bit but it seems beyond me.

EDIT

I've spent some time experimenting with an alternative solution. I made a secondary key as a potential primary key that forced all of bars to be contiguous and in a known range for each partition. I then created a second comparable partitioned table using ranged partitioning to do some testing.

Some things I have found are:

1. Using a range or two in the where (`WHERE 50000 <= bar_id AND 50500 < bar_id`) does trigger constraint exclusion
2. Using a large* where "list", whether as a pure `IN` clause or an `IN (VALUES...)` does not trigger constraint exclusion
3. *However, using a list of 100 or fewer values in an `IN` clause, does  trigger constraint exclusion. Anymore than that, and something else kicks in in PostgreSQL's backend query planner.

Other things I also tried were union-alling chunks of queries batched in groups of 100 bars, which does trigger constraint exclusion for each sub-set query, but is not as fast as using a X < bar < Y range. Your mileage may vary here.

That being said, both versions were >10X faster than before, so mission accomplished in a sense. I plan to use my application logic to create smart ranges, rather than using chunks of 100, perhaps unless I have very disparate bar_ids (which I foresee as unlikely, TBD).

Hopefully this helps others looking to use PG partitioning.

If anyone who works on PG can comment on what's happening both with the prior 'list' version and the range with list>100, that would be very helpful and interesting.

Note that I hypothesize -- for list based partitioning -- that using a list of 100 or fewer in the partition *definitions* might allow constraint exclusion to kick in, as the logic that prevents it in the range partition testing I did may be shared by the partition pruning logic as well, where it just gives up no matter what if the list definition is greater than 100 items.

Comment: Your hypothesis is correct that list partitions with more than 100 values in its list of values cannot be pruned by constraint exclusion.  PostgreSQL 11 is able to prune such list partitions though, because it has a new pruning mechanism which doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, amil. Are there any restrictions on constraint exclusion in PG11?

Comment: If you're still planning to use declarative partitioned tables in PG 11, then constraint exclusion is irrelevant.  As I mentioned in the previous comment, PG 11 uses a new method that doesn't have the 100-value-list restriction discussed in your question.

Comment: Right. I suppose my question should have been more precise. You state it "doesn't have the 100-value-list restriction". Are there any *other* restrictions, beside that one which no longer exists? Or are all filters possible such that the new method always works?

Comment: Yeah, the new method should always work.